# Assign timezone to a Python datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

Assume that I have a timezone-less `datetime` object:

```
import datetime
import pytz
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
dtUnaware = datetime.datetime(1979,2,20,6)
print(dtUnaware.strftime(fmt))
```

This yields:

```
1979-02-20 06:00:00
```

So far, so good. Now, I want to assign a timezone to this object. It seems like I could use either [`datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) or [`pytz.localize`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic).

First:

```
dtAware1 = dtUnaware.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem'))
print(dtAware1.strftime(fmt))
```

returns: `1979-02-20 06:00:00 LMT+0221`. Secondly:

```
dtAware2 = pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem').localize(dtUnaware, is_dst=None)
print(dtAware2.strftime(fmt))
```

returns `1979-02-20 06:00:00 IST+0200`.

What's wrong with the first method? It seems to assign a wrong timezone. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From Pytz documentation : *This library differs from the documented Python API for
tzinfo implementations; if you want to create local wallclock
times you need to use the `localize()` method documented in this
document... Unfortunately these
issues cannot be resolved without modifying the Python datetime
implementation (see PEP-431)*

My reading of that is that a `pytz` timezone is not exactly the same thing as a standard timezone. If you had a genuine timezone, first method should be good, but you have not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in the `datetime` API: when you assign a timezone to it, the timezone is not given the opportunity to know the date and time it should be configured for. The historical database that `pytz` uses goes back a long way, often to periods when the timezone name or offset were different than the ones in use today. Without being given the chance to adjust to a specific date period, the details of the timezone may be wrong.

Using `localize` is the way around this problem, since both the date and timezone are available within the function at the same time.

Comment: a good explanation. It might be worth mentioning `localize()`'s `is_dst` parameter that handles ambiguous and non-existent local times. Also `normalize()` method could be used after `localize()` for non-existent local time.